# Boost websocket accept hangs

Tags: c++, boost, websocket

I copied the simple boost websocket example from [here](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_66_0/libs/beast/example/websocket/client/sync/websocket_client_sync.cpp) and [here](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_66_0/libs/beast/example/websocket/server/sync/websocket_server_sync.cpp), and that worked fine. I then added these lines to the server just before the call to create the websocket:

```
boost::beast::flat_buffer buffer;
boost::beast::http::request<boost::beast::http::string_body> req;
boost::beast::http::read(sock, buffer, req);
```

Thse lines are taken from [this page](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/develop/libs/beast/doc/html/beast/ref/boost__beast__websocket__is_upgrade.html) to read the contents of the message before upgrading to a websocket. Both the server and client now hang on the websocket handshake.

Am I doing something wrong or is this a bug in boost?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are going to read the WebSocket upgrade request yourself, then in order to accept the upgrade request you need to use the correct overload of `websocket::stream::accept` or `websocket::stream::async_accept`. Use an overload which accepts the HTTP request in the first parameter:
https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_66_0/libs/beast/doc/html/beast/ref/boost__beast__websocket__stream/accept/overload6.html
https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_66_0/libs/beast/doc/html/beast/ref/boost__beast__websocket__stream/async_accept/overload3.html

Comment: Thank you! That's exactly it!